# Expected a value of type 'List<dynamic>', but got one of type '_JsonMap'

Tags: flutter

when I try to decode the json I'm getting this error
`Expected a value of type 'List<dynamic>', but got one of type '_JsonMap'`

List paymentList = [];

This is what I tried

`

```
List paymentList =[];
Future getPayment() async {
  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('myUrl'),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $authToken'
    },
  );
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    setState(() {
      paymentList=jsonDecode(response.body);
    });
  } else {
    dev.log("++++++++++Status Code +++++++++++++++");
    dev.log(response.statusCode.toString());
  }
}
```

`

Comment: Please share your response Json response body

Comment: Can you share your response body and class of paymentList object.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment you did in **setState** `paymentList=jsonDecode(response.body);` indicates that response.body is **Map** and you are assigning it to `paymentList` which is of type **List**.

Comment: List paymentList =[];

Comment: try this paymentList = jsonDecode(response.body).map((e) =>  e).toList();

Comment: tried, but not working

Comment: What error you are getting after doing above changes?

Comment: Expected a value of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>', but got one of type '(dynamic) => dynamic'